# Assume $\gcd(a, m) > 1$. Show that there cannot possibly exist a power $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1 \bmod m$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

i have no idea where to start to show this. i'm assuming that i should probably use Fermat little theorem and division algorithm. but i don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you mean $a^k$ or $ak$?

Comment: i meant a^k sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ a^k\equiv 1\pmod m\,\Rightarrow\,jm + a^k = 1\,$ so $\,d\mid m,a\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid jm + a^k = 1,\,$ if $\ k> 0$

And 
$\ \ \, ak\equiv 1\pmod m\,\Rightarrow\,jm + ak = 1\,$ so $\,d\mid m,a\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid jm + ak = 1$

Note that the first is a special case of the second, since $\,a(a^{k-1})\equiv 1$

Generally, units (= invertibles = divisors of $1$) [cannot be](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606996/242) zero-divisors (except in a trivial ring).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is $k>0$ such that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Then there is some integer $z$ such that
$$
a^k=1+mz\implies [a^{k-1}]a+[-z]m=1\iff ra+sm=1\text{ where }r=a^{k-1}, s=-z.
$$
This is a Bezout's identity for $a$ and $m$ that implies $\text{gcd}(a,m)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If such $k$ exists then the eqation $ax\equiv 1\bmod m$ has a solution (i.e., $x=a^{k-1}$). while the equation $ax\equiv 1\bmod m$ has a solution if and only if $\gcd(a,m)=1$.