# $ a\in \Bbb Z_n$ is invertible $\,\Rightarrow\gcd (a,n) =1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with this:

If a is an element of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\gcd(a,n) > 1$ , then a is not invertible.

First you show that if $a$ is an element of $\mathbb Z_n$ and $\gcd(a,n)>1$, then there 
is an element $b$ of $\mathbb Z_n$ and ($b$ is not equal to the zero element) from
which $ab = 0$.

The second part I cant get. i.e. show if $b$ is not the zero element 
and $ab=0$ then $a$ is not invertible.

Comment: Suppose to the contrary that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. Then $ab=1+kn$ for some integer $k$. If $d$ divides $a$ and $n$, then $d$ divides $1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is the special case $\,\color{0a0}{b = 1}\,$ of the following solvability criterion.

$\qquad \exists\, x\!:\ ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}\iff \exists\, x,y\!:\ ax+ny = b\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm Bezout\!\!\!\!}\Longleftarrow}\!\color{}{\Longrightarrow}\, \gcd(a,n)\mid b $

**Remark** $\ $ The OP only requires the simpler black direction $\,(\Longrightarrow),\,$ not the deeper reverse arrow $(\color{#c00}\Longleftarrow)$ using $\rm\color{#c00}{Bezout's}\,$ identity for the gcd.

A more general ring-theoretic understanding comes from viewing it as a special case of the fact that [zero-divisors are *never* invertible (in nonzero-rings)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606950/multiplicative-inverses-for-z-n).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767456/242).

Answer (score 1):

Assume $ab = 0$ and at the same time that $a$ is invertible. That means that there exists an $a^{-1}$ such that $a^{-1}a = 1$ But then we have
$$
b = 1\cdot b = a^{-1}ab = a^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0
$$
so there cannot be a $b \neq 0$ such that $ab = 0$. That means that if there *is* such a $b$, then $a$ cannot be invertible.

Comment: i.e. a **zero-divisor is not invertible** (in a nonzero ring). This is a generalization of the more widely known fact that zero is not invertible in a field or domain.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose gcd(a,n)=1
We can write this as: ax+ny=1
And class of ax+ny is equal to class of 1
cl(ax+ny)=cl(1)
cl(ax)+cl(ny)=cl(1)
We know about class of zero i.e (cl(0)={0+ny\y belongs to Z})
From this we can write:
cl(ax)+cl(0)=cl(1)
cl(ax)=cl(1)
cl(a).cl(x)=cl(1)
cl(a)^-1=cl(x)
So cl(a) is Invertible

Conversely,
Suppose that cl(a) is Invertible
Then there exist an element cl(x) of Zn other than cl(0) such that
cl(a).cl(x)=cl(1)
cl(ax)=cl(1)
ax=1 mod(n)
n|(ax-1)
ax-1=ny (y belongs to Integers)
ax-ny=1
ax+n(-y)=1
gcd(a,n)=1

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).