# Number theory proofs

Tags: number-theory

1. Prove that if $\gcd(a,m)>1$, then $a^k\not\equiv1$ (mod $m$) for all $k\ge1$.

I know that the best way to do this is to prove it by contradiction. So, we say that $a^k \equiv 1$ (mod $m$). Also, we know that $a$ and $m$ are not relatively prime. I also feel like this proof would need Fermat’s little Theorem.

2. Suppose $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Let $j$ be the order of $a$ modulo $m$. Prove that if $a^k\equiv1$ (mod $m$), then $j∣k$.

Comment: Are there questions here?

Comment: I don’t know how to go on.

Comment: Why $\gcd(a,m)$ twice?

Comment: Oh sorry typo..

Comment: I wondered whether there was a typo on a second condition.

Comment: Why are people downvoting my post? Can you at least tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: $(1)\ \bmod m\!:\ a^k\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{-1}$ exists $\, \Rightarrow\,\gcd(a,m)=1\,$ [by Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1204444/242). $(2)$ is by [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really contradiction that you have to use, but rather a proof by contrapositive: show that if $a^k\equiv 1\pmod m$, then $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

For the second point, it has nothing to do with Fermat: it is a general result in group theory that if an element $g$ satisfies $g^k=e$ (the unit element of the groupˆ), then $k$ is a multiple of the order of $g$. It simply results from the  group homomorphism
\begin{align}
(\mathbf Z,+)&\longrightarrow (G,\cdot), \\
k&\longmapsto g^k,
\end{align}
and $\mathbf Z$ being a P.I.D. (the order of $g$ is the positive generator of the kernel).

Comment: I understand your point, but for number 1, how would you do that. I know that from the definition of modulo, m divides a^k-1. What would I do from there?

Comment: Write $a^k=bm+1$ and  conclude that any common divisor of $a$ and $m$ divides $1$.