# Invertible element can't be nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

When I was reviewing cracking GRE subject mathematics 4-th edition, I was confused about the proof in Page 247.

> Consider invertible element c in a Ring, $cc^{-1} = 1$. Then for any integer n, $(cc^{-1})^{n} = 1$, which means $c^{n}c^{-n} = 1$. Then $c^{n}$ can't be zero for any n, which means c can't be nilpotent.

I was wondering if $(cc^{-1})^{n} = c^{n}c^{-n}$ is satisfied for any Ring? I think it's satisfied only if it comes to a commutative ring (multiplication is commutative).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More generally nilpotent $\Rightarrow$ [zero-divisor $\Rightarrow$ not invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606996/242), since invertibles (units) are cancellable.

Comment: This is not accurate for another reason. In the zero ring, $0$ is both invertible and nilpotent. Of course, this is the only counterexample.

Comment: I guess the proof is avoiding the (far simpler?) proof by contradiction?  If $c^n=0$ with $n>1$ minimal, then obviously $c^{n-1}=0$ after cancelling a copy of $c$, and you have a contradiction without any need to discuss commuting.

Answer (score 7):

In any ring an invertible element commutes with its inverse.

Answer (score 3):

In any ring $R$, if any two elements $a,b\in R$ commutes then the identity $$(ab)^n=a^nb^n$$
holds true. It is not necessary that the whole ring should be commutative. Therefore in your case because $cc^{-1}=1=c^{-1}c$, it implies that $c$ and $c^{-1}$ commutes. So that $c^nc^{-n}=(cc^{-1})^n=1.$

Answer (score 2):

Both $(cc^{-1})^n = (c c^{-1}) (c c^{-1}) \cdots (c c^{-1}) = 1$ and $c^n c^{-n} = (c c \cdots c) (c^{-1} c^{-1} \cdots c^{-1}) = 1$, so naturally they are equal.

Comment: Because $c$ and $c^{-1}$ commute.

Comment: @runway44 This proof doesn’t use that (even though it’s true): In the first case, you simplify each pair to a $1$ and end up with a product of ones; in the second case, you simplify from the middle outwards, i.e. you place parentheses like this: $c(c(\cdots(c(cc^{-1})c^{-1})\cdots)c^{-1})c^{-1}$.